# static variables memory allocation in one system to another system if java is platform independent?

Tags: java

static variable memory allocation is done at compilation time only if java is platform independent then how the other system jvm use the variable or it again compiles static variables in other system to allocate memory?

Comment: Can you show some examples what you mean?

Comment: static variables and blocks loaded at compilation time .if java is plat form independent then if the class files will be executed in another another system what is situation for static variables memory allocation in another system>

Comment: @vinod That's not what `static` means in the Java language. `static` simply means that a variable is a member of a class. The class is actually an object, and memory for its members isn't allocated until the class is referenced at runtime. Then memory for the class is allocated, and the class is loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

> static variables and blocks loaded at compilation time

It only means that these are written into the generated class files. The actual memory allocation happens at run-time, when the class is loaded. The executing JVM performs the actual allocation of the static variables and the execution of the static blocks.